# Can multiple services (on different ports) use the same SSL cert?

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

Can I use the same SSL certificate for a Tomcat service on port 443, and for a separate IIS service on some other port? Both services live on the same machine, on the same IP address and have the same DNS entry.

If so, how would I convert the certificate (issued for Tomcat/java) to a form that IIS7 can handle?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, absolutely - those services can both use the same certificate.

Can you clarify what format the certificate is in now (in a java keystore, or x509, or maybe pkcs12)?  We can definitely provide some assistance in getting it converted with further details.

Comment: Certificate is currently in java keystore format.